# Firefox ignoring download directory

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying download something by clicking a button in firefox and everything works fine except that it looks like it ignores the download  directory and put's everything  in the Downloads folder. While the code was running I checked at `about:config` on firefox and it had as download directory what i had set on the code, but still nothing. Here's my code right now:

```
def Firefox_Profile(download_directory):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(download_directory)
    profile.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 0)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_directory)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
    profile.set_preference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ".mp3 audio/mpeg")

    return profile


 def get_user_choice():
    input("press enter when ready to choose the list of songs")
    songs_list = askopenfilename(initialdir='.')

    if not songs_list:
        raise ValueError("You did not choose the songs list file.")
    if not songs_list.endswith("txt"):
        raise ValueError("A text file must be chosen.")

    input("press enter when ready to choose the download directory")
    download_directory = askdirectory(initialdir='.')

    if not download_directory:
        raise ValueError("You did not choose the download directory.")
        return songs_list, download_directory

songs_list, download_directory = get_user_choice()


driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=Firefox_Profile(download_directory))
```

Answer (score 0):

To initiate a new *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Quantum Client* session through `Firefox_Profile()` with a pre-defined **download_directory** as per the *API Documentation* of [`Firefox_Profile()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile) you have two options as follows :

- Either you can invoke a new *Firefox Profile* on each new execution and invoke the new *Firefox Profile* during *Firefox Session* initiation as follows :

  ```
  def Firefox_Profile(download_directory):
      profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
      profile.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 0)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_directory)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
      profile.set_preference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", False)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
      profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ".mp3 audio/mpeg")
      return profile

  #Invoking the _Firefox Profile_
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  ```
- Or you can invoke an existing *Firefox Profile* by passing the absolute path of the *Firefox Profile* as an argument and invoke the new *Firefox Profile* during *Firefox Session* initiation as follows  :

  ```
  def Firefox_Profile(download_directory):
      profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\moskcpdq.SeleniumTest')
      profile.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 0)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_directory)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
      profile.set_preference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", False)
      profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
      profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ".mp3 audio/mpeg")
      return profile

  #Invoking the _Firefox Profile_
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  ```